# Powershell Search String in File Containing $

Tags: string, file, powershell, search

I want to search the following string in a text file: `$$u$$`

I tried `select-string`, `get-content`, `.Contains`. It seems to me it's not possible.

I used this for the search as a variable: `$ToSearch = "'$'$u'$'$"`

It always gives false result.

Answer (score 1):

It is because most search filters are relying on regex. The $ symbol in regex needs to be escaped

Without knowing more of what you're trying to accomplish I can't give much of an example, but here is one:

```
'this is a $$u$$ test' -replace "\$",""
```

The '\' is what is escaping the character - meaning to translate it literally.

Edit: Per comment

```
$Val = 'this is a $$u$$ test'
$Val | Select-String "\$+\w\$+" -quiet
```

-Quiet switch returns t/f rather than a string value.

Comment: I only want to have a binary answer (TRUE/FALSE) whether this string can be found or not in the text file. More lines can contain this but one occurence is already enough for a TRUE result.

Comment: Edited answer with something that might be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

The $ is a reserved character in regex, which is complicating your search.

The default search pattern type for Select-String is regex, but you can also specify `-Simplematch` or `-Wildcard`, either of which will eliminate the need to escape the $.  If you use -Wildcard, you'll need to include the wilcard * at either end of the match - `'*$$u$$*'`.  For simplematch, just use the string you want to match for - `'$$u$$'`.

Comment: Just don't forget to single quote the pattern because `$` is also a special character in PowerShell and is evaluated in a double quoted string.

Comment: $true dat.  Best practice is to only double quote when the string contains variables and/or sub-expressions you explicitly want expanded.